# how to load the images from firebase database into stack of cards like tinder in android using firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

How to load the images from Firebase database node (some times number of images may be 100, 200, like that variable count). How to load them into stack of cards like tinder in Android using Firebase. Do I need to load all the 100 or 200 images once into stack of cards, or do i need to load them in chukns? each time when i swipe the card , card should be destroyed/deleted.

Regards,
Srini

Answer (score 0):

You can use firebase realtime database for storage and firebase cloud messaging for chat among them..
When user sign up.. just make a node of them in firebase realtime db.

Comment: I am storing the images in the firebase storage only..my question is how to retrieve those images and show them in the stack of cards like tinder in android..i am very much aware of recycler view, but i dont want to use recyclerview...i want to display each image like stack of cards like tinder  and each time when i swipe the card, the image should be destroyed or deleted.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to load all the 100 or 200 images once into stack of cards, or do i need to load them in chukns?

It is always recommended to get the exact ammount data that you need and nothing more. Loading unnecessary basically represents a waste your bandwidth. In your case, since you have a single list of images, you can generate a random image and create a single call. There is no need to get all 100 or 200 images.

Comment: Hi srini! Have you tried my solution above, does it work?